# Writing a regular expression with decimal values

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression for use in Google Course Builder. The expression needs to  accept `22.69 - 23` inclusive.

The decimals are beating me! Help would be greatly appreciated. Google Course Builder uses expressions in this format: `\b0*(2[89]|[34][0-9]|50)\b`

Comment: what are the possible input values look like and what is the expected output?

Comment: @Dalorzo: I assume possible input values could be anything, but that it must match an input value that is a number between 22.69 and 23.00 inclusive.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am assuming a few things as well :D that is why I wanted to clarify

Comment: IMO, a regex is a poor tool for this job. I'd use a regex to recognize that it's a valid FP number, then if it is, convert the input and check if it's in range.

Comment: Agree @Dalorzo... then there's "what have you tried?"   Jerry Coffin:  in my opinion, that depends entirely on the input.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: There's actually an [online utility](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) that builds regexes like this.  Unfortunately, it doesn't support decimals.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Oh, there's no question that an RE *can* recognize this. The question is whether it's a good idea. And (it seems to me) the answer to that is a pretty clear "no".

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I don't see why not.  Especially when the creation of the regex can actually be automated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Primarily because by the time you have a result that really works correctly, it's almost completely unreadable. Consider what woot's will look like by the time he's added enough to ignore leading 0's *and* recognize `e` notation like `2.27e+1`. Leading zeros is pretty easy, but dealing with `e` notation in an RE looks decidedly non-trivial to me.

Answer (score 1):

If I break it down, I think you are looking for these matches:

```
 \b0*(22\.69[0-9]*|22\.[7-9][0-9]*|23|23\.0*)\b
```

That is:

```
22.69
22.7*
22.8*
22.9*
23
23.0...
```

Does that regex work for your use?  Also, I'm not sure which regex it is, you might need to escape the decimal.

Comment: You want `22.69*`, not just 22.69 (e.g., 22.691 should be accepted).

Comment: Ahh I wasn't really thinking of precision, but that's easy enough to add.

Comment: how about 00000022.89?

Comment: As noted in my comment to Robert Harvey above, you should also recognize things like `2.27e+1`, `0.227e+2` or `2271e-3` (though I think this may be quite difficult in a RE). Although I can't quite imagine anybody wanting to do it, there's no particularly good reason that `0.0000000000227e+8` shouldn't work as well.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to nearly be there. 23.00 should be the max value, but '23' need to work too.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think it just depends on his input.  If the input won't come in with that form then there is no need to go off into the weeds and support it.

Comment: If a program rejected FP input in that form, *my* "RE" engine would reject the program.